# Changing part of a row name in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame of values for the total abundance and weight of a shellfish species with estimated variation for a number of ages at 8 sites. E.g.

```
        0               1        2       3    All
```

Site1.tot.num.est
Site1.var.num.est
Site1.tot.wt.est
Site1.var.wt.est
Site2.tot.num.est
Site2.var.num.est

I would like to keep the site names as they are but change the end of the row name to something more suitable e.g. Site1.Overall abundance, Site1. Overall variance (abundance) etc. I am not sure if this can be done simply within R i.e. if it is possible to apply a line of code to each variation of the end of the row title irrespective of the site?

Comment: Not sure I understand this correctly.  May be you can use `regex` to remove the part of the string and then `paste` the `Overallabundance`  i.e. `rownames(df1) <- paste0(sub('\\..*', '', rownames(df1)), '.Overallabundance')`

Comment: The data frame you have posted doesn't look like a data frame to me. Could you post the output of `dput(head(dat))` (where `dat` is your data frame) so we can see what your data looks like?

Comment: In addition to @josilber's comment, it would be helpful to show the expected output based on the example data.

Comment: It won't let me paste the output in but I think the structure is a list but the class is data frame

Comment: You can use the edit button and then paste the output

Comment: This is what I would like it to look like: 
Site1.Overall abundance
Site1.Overall variance
Site2.Overall abundance
Site2.Overallvariance
Site3. Overall abundance
Site3.Overall variance

Comment: Based on the input dataset, the 'Site' in the rownames and in the expected output are not matching.  You have `Site3` which is not there.

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps

```
indx <- grepl('var', v1)
v1[indx] <- paste0(sub('\\..*', '', v1[indx]), '.Overall_variance')
v1[!indx] <- paste0(sub('\\..*', '', v1[!indx]), '.Overall_abundance')
v1
#[1] "Site1.Overall_abundance" "Site1.Overall_variance" 
#[3] "Site1.Overall_abundance" "Site1.Overall_variance" 
#[5] "Site2.Overall_abundance" "Site2.Overall_variance"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('Site1.tot.num.est','Site1.var.num.est','Site1.tot.wt.est',
 'Site1.var.wt.est','Site2.tot.num.est','Site2.var.num.est')
```

NOTE: Change `v1` with `rownames(yourdataset)`